# arguments with defined type in PHP

Tags: php, function, types, integer

I have defined this code :

```
function calcule (integer $a, integer $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

$num1=5;
$num2=6;
echo calcule($num1, $num2);
```

it's giving the following errors :

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to calcule() must be an instance of integer, integer given, called in /home/me/calcule.php on line 9 and defined in /home/stephane/public_html/calcule.php on line 3
>   PHP Stack trace:-
>
> PHP   1. {main}() /home/me/calcule.php:0
>
> PHP   2. calcule() /home/me/calcule.php:9

Comment: You need not to use `integer ` with params, check this : https://eval.in/591273

Comment: Which version of php you use??

Answer (score 2):

Type declarations is allow in [**PHP 7.0.x**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) as

> Scalar type declarations come in two flavours: coercive (default) and
>   strict. The following types for parameters can now be enforced (either
>   coercively or strictly): strings (string), integers (int),
>   floating-point numbers (float), and booleans (bool). They augment the
>   other types introduced in PHP 5: class names, interfaces, array and
>   callable.

```
function calcule (int $a, int $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

$num1=5;
$num2=6;
echo calcule($num1, $num2);
```

UP to `PHP 5.6.x`  version you not need to define it

just use it as

```
function calcule ($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

$num1=5;
$num2=6;
echo calcule($num1, $num2);
```